# Selected selector not working

Tags: jquery, html, select, jquery-selectors

i am learning about the jquery selectors and i have created a small exmaple. I have created select box and when i select anything it should show what i have selected.But unfortunately my example is not running.I am making small mistake.The jsfiddle demo: [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5pSfs/)Thanks
Here is my code :

dashboard.php

```
   <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>selected demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="garden" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Flowers</option>
  <option selected="selected">Shrubs</option>
  <option>Trees</option>
  <option selected="selected">Bushes</option>
  <option>Grass</option>
  <option>Dirt</option>
</select>
<div></div>



</body>
</html>
```

ajax.js

```
$( "select" )
      .change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
          str += $( this ).text() + " ";
        });
        $( "div" ).text( str );
      })
      .trigger( "change" );
```

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery. Otherwise your code just works:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/5pSfs/1/

Comment: ohh great not its working now i have a small question now if i want to database and pass this string to database then how to pass it ?

Comment: That would be a different question altogether. Please ask a new question clearly stating your problem along with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi but when i create a separate file for js and html its not showing any outut i need to pass select id in such case right ?

Comment: yes. you should provide unique ids to your elements. that will help you to select just the element you want.

Comment: I think :selected is for checkboxes

Comment: @Kermani: that would be `:checked` and yes, `:checked` could be used for `select`s too! See this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5pSfs/2/

Comment: yes true its for checkbox so while using select box how can we get hte id'S for elements so that i can pass it to my database for queryig ?

Comment: @user3702602: You don't retrieve ids for selected options, you need values for them. I would suggest that you go thru a kind of tutorial  first to get a hold on how things work. StackOverflow will help you if you are stuck later, once you have attained a reasonable level of understanding.

Comment: @abhitalks in the fiddle you uploaded what does trigger do? http://fiddle.jshell.net/5pSfs/2/

Comment: @Kermani: It is triggering the `change` event on page load, so that the code could run once in the start. BTW: It is not *my* fiddle. It was taken from the Op's question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get selected value simply this way:

```
$("select").change(function() {

var val = $(this).val(); // will get selected option value

var text = $(this).text(); // will get select option text

});
```